# How to plot a histogram using ggplot2 in a shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am trying to plot a histogram using ggplot in a shiny app.
I have a data frame(called x) with 3 columns, each column contains a bunch of zeros, ones, twos and threes (categorical variables). My aim is for a user too select one of the columns from a drop down list and a histogram of the data in that column should appear.
In normal R Markdown I got the following histogram by using ggplot2.

```
 ggplot(x, aes(col1)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, colour = "steelblue4", fill = "steelblue3" )
```

[image]

This is exactly what I want.

However I do not get that when doing it in my shiny app.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Step 2"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("sym", "Choose ",
                  colnames(x))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(x, aes(input$sym)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, colour = "steelblue4", fill = "steelblue3" ) 
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get the following error.

> StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

I did try to use stat_count instead of geom_histogram but it resulted in something like this,

[image]

I also tried adding stat = "count" like the error suggests but I end up with the exact same error.
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Additional question.
Can I share this interactive document with someone who does not have R?

Comment: I believe you want `aes_string` instead of `aes` as you pass it a character value with the column name.

Comment: O my word it worked. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there any way that I can share this interactive document with someone who does not have R?

Comment: You can share your shiny app as a web page. See tutorial for details: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson7/

Comment: If I share it as a web page will anyone be able to access the data? Or will people only have access to the document and not the data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your web page can display an interactive plot of the data and table of the data. It can also have a button to download the data if you wanted. Did you look at the tutorial?